# App goes background after using for sometime

Tags: android, performance, android-viewpager

My requirement is like I need to show some 12 view pager with 4 pages and recyclerview inside with 5 contents. That 12 number is dynamic, so am doing like, in one linearlayout adding viewpager programitically. The issue is like in some phones on continuous scroll after sometime app goes background with high memory usages.
Can anyone suggest some good way to do this scenario.

Comment: why don't you try recyclerview with items as viewpager and other 5 contents.  You can use different  **`ItemViewType`** to use that 5 contents and viewpager in single recyclerview.

Comment: refer [**`this`**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37789091/viewpager-inside-recyclerview-as-row-item) and [**`this`**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26245139/how-to-create-recyclerview-with-multiple-view-type)