# ViewPager in RecyclerView element

Tags: android, android-volley

I'm trying to create a recyclerview with a viewpager per element.
Each element has its own photos that I fetch from the server with a JSON Array. I want it to look like this:
[image]

[image]

Comment: Please avoid using links and upload the picture instead ..also the link is unable to be opened and is requesting access..

Comment: @Narendra_Nath Done

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37789091/viewpager-inside-recyclerview-as-row-item i think this is what you're looking for